# jQuery multiple setTimeout code mess

Tags: jquery, animation, settimeout

I'm trying to create an animation by using the setTimeout function in jQuery. This works out well and the animation works perfect, but my code is such a mess now.

```
setTimeout(function() {
            $('p').fadeOut();

            setTimeout(function() {
                var heightLoading = $('#loading').height();
                $("#loading").css("margin-top", height);
                $('#loading').html("Anyways, I am a <span>Web Designer</span> and <span>Front-end Developper</span>").fadeIn();

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#name').fadeIn();
                }, 2000);
            }, 1000)
        }, 3000);

      }, 800);
}, 2000);
```

Is there a different way of doing this? Now it is a setTimeout in a setTimeout, etc. This is really confusing if I go on like this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the chaining a bit by skipping the setTimeout and using the built in timing and callback:

```
$('p').fadeOut(800, function () { var heighLoading....
```

If you want to remove the function nesting even more there is a plugin here that might help:

http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/

Comment: Thanks! I used the plugin! Works great!

Comment: Is this the best way of doing this? Or is it better to use for example CSS?